# Calculate $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{1}{xy}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Calculate $\lim_\limits{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\left(\dfrac{1}{xy}\right)$

Does it exist?

If we choose path along x-axis, then we have $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1}{0}$

Similarly if we choose path along y-axis, then we have $\lim_{y\to 0}\dfrac{1}{0}$

I also see no other substitution that would yield a proper limit.

Any hints. Thank you

Comment: It doesn't exist; not even in the extended reals. You can make the limit go to either $\pm \infty$ by approaching $(0,0)$ in a different way.

Comment: Try approaching along the lines $y = x$ and $y = -x$.

Comment: The expression $\frac{1}{xy}$ is not defined on the $x$ or $y$ axis. Choosing a path along one of the axes is nonsense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit does not exist.

For $x=y$, the limit would be $\infty$, and for $x=-y$, it would be $-\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Most often you can reject the existence by using $x=ym$, in which $m\in \mathbb{R}$ hence:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{1}{xy}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1}{my^2}.$$

As 5xum already suggested, you will see that the limit depends on the choice of $m$, hence the limit cannot exist.